# How to add line break character on my widget's javascript for Nokia WRT?

Tags: javascript, rss, newline, nokia-wrt

If anybody like me is using *Nokia WRT Plug-in for Visual Studio*...

I've created on Visual Studio a Rss Reader Widget.

Now I'm customizing it, trying to add line breaks in rss tag called "< description>".

I'm trying many codes like with no luck:

```
"Fist line\u000dSecond line"
"Fist line\u000dSecond line"
"Fist line\nSecond line"
"Fist line& #xD;Second line" --> remove space here :)
"Fist line<br>Second line"
```

I'm also digging more to find out what's up with html format, since CDATA is not working to present formatted content (I have to use clean text in my rss file).

thanks in advance

Comment: And double backslashes in case the string is used in some mysterious ways? `\\n`

Comment: yes I tried \r\n and double backslashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a clutter solution:

- my rss content is generated dynamically on a aspx page (response content type is rss format).
- nokia widget is able to read a url location, in this case my rss url location: http://localhost/mysite/rss.aspx
- since line breaks symbols defined in my rss output are not understood by nokia's javacript function getContentHTMLForFeedItem, I changed rss content:

  "First line; Second line"
- Now javascript reads this rss content as valid. It's time to force a line break.
- To force line break, I changed getContentHTMLForFeedItem function as follows:

  ```
   // Returns the content HTML for a feed item.
   function getContentHTMLForFeedItem(item) {
         var buf = "";

         // item description
         if (item.description != null) {
               var linebreaked = "" + item.description;

            while (linebreaked.indexOf("; ") > 0)
                  linebreaked = linebreaked.replace("; ", "[br]");

            buf += "[div class=\"FeedItemDescription\"]" + linebreaked + "[/div]";
   }
  ```
- Note: Change the brackets to less than "<" and greater than signs ">".

If anyone is having the same problem or if I'm doing something wrong, please let me know.